# Structuring User Data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting up a new web service, and need some help with organizing the data in my application. My application's written in PHP, and I plan to store all user data in using MySQL Databases.

I will have a bunch of users, and each of those users will have a bunch of data that is tied to their account. It's a note taking application, and so, naturally, for every user, I need to keep track of the number of notes, and the content of each of those notes.

How do I go about structuring this and translating this into MySQL tables? I know I have to do something that revolves around linked (related) tables, but can't seem to pinpoint it.

I have 10x1GB databases.

Comment: So what's the question? If the tables are created with correct "relationships" to each other then everything will just roll-up around applicable query lines. (And why have multiple databases?)

Comment: To start. Think about having a `Note` table that has all of the information related to a single note. Also have a column of `user_id` (or something similar) that relates it to a user in the `User` table.

Comment: There are many "SQL/RDBMS design tutorials" on-line, should probably read one (or a few).

Answer (score 3):

Have the following tables (you can choose your own names);

```
tbl_users
int(4)       userid (PRIMARY)
varchar(128) firstname
varchar(128) lastname

tbl_notes
int(8)       noteid (PRIMARY)
int(4)       userid
text         notecontent
```

As you can see, `userid` is the relation between the two tables (1 to many in this case).

See [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) from Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

Try following queries to create your tables:

**Users:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Notes:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```